# Not able to pull docker images - load metadata error with Mac M1 chip ( image not found )

Tags: docker, apple-m1, dockerhub

i am trying to build docker images and later pull them for deployment locally. The process runs fine on a mac with intel chip, but not one with m1 chip.

```
error: ERROR: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: artifactory.io/image-name:latest: not found
```

I reviewed docker documentation, to see if i can enable more detailed logging. Tried a couple of them, but did not give me more details. Please help with how to dig into more details on what is happening.

**Note**: we use docker buildx so that images are built for multi-architecture setup. Also, the image size on Intel and Mac chip is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should check these steps:

1. the name of your dockerfile is Dockerfile (with capital letter)
2. avoid to use [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/build/#to-enable-buildkit-builds):

   `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`

   `export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0`

Comment: Thank you. Tried the suggestions and i still see the same error.

Comment: have you tried to execute the build command like this?
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0  docker build .